# RoadLink and RoadArea topological relation in INSPIRE

Tags: topology, inspire

I have some confusion about RoadLink and RoadArea topological relation in INSPIRE (Infrastructure for Spatial Information in the European Community).

If I got this correctly:

- RoadLinks are connected at the intersections.
- RoadLink must be inside it's RoadArea.
- RoadAreas must not intersect.

**So my question is**: How can I solve topology on the intersection? If I keep the RoadLinks connected then the RoadAreas will intersect. If I trim the RoadAreas (dashed line between two RoadAreas at the picture below) than RoadLink will be outside it's RoadArea.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably worth asking on the INSPIRE thematic clusters pages ~ https://themes.jrc.ec.europa.eu/groups/profile/209/topo-cadastre-reference-data